# Creating Two version of a Laravel Website

Tags: php, laravel, responsive-design

I am new in Laravel.

I am using PHP [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) Class to using different website version for my users. For example if a user is browsing by website by his mobile The site show him a mobile compatible version with limited option and if he is visiting my website by his PC and he can see the full version of my website.

I know responsive design by CSS but I need to have a light website, I know Facebook, Google and Ebay are responsive by detecting mobile from server side.

**How can I do this in Laravel?**

Should I put my **if conditions** before each route? or in views? or another better way?

Comment: Check if its mobile or desktop, and then just define globally view path or routes.
if(mobile)
 $view_path = 'master.mobile.layouts';
else
....

or do the same with routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper method like this:

```
public static function makeView($viewName, $data = array()) {
        if (self::isMobile()) {
            $viewName .= '_mobile';
        }
        return View::make($viewName, $data);
}
```

and use `makeView` instead of View::make, create every layout with one postfixed with _mobile as well, and then add an `isMobile` method to your class.